# Cannot install Microsoft SQL driver for PHP 5.6 on Windows

Tags: php, sql-server, apache

I have been trying all day long and nothing. No sqlsrv extension, no logs, nothing. The `sqlsrv_connect()` function is not defined and I don't see the extension in `phpinfo()`. I tried WAMP at first. It didn't work. Now I am doing it bit by bit.

- I have **Windows 10**
- I installed **SQL Express 2005** (is what I need for RMS).
- I installed **Apache 2.4.16** (x86) in *C:\Apache\apache24* from [here](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/)
- I installed **PHP 5.6.12 TS** (x86) in *C:\PHP\php5_6_12* from [here](http://windows.php.net/download/)
- Configured Apache to load *php5apache2_4.dll* (and changed several other settings so it can run PHP files)
- I downloaded **Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server** (file *SQLSRV32.EXE*) from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098)
- I extracted *php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll* and *php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll* to the *ext* folder of PHP
- Set up *extension_dir* like `extension_dir = "ext"`
- Added the extensions to *php.ini*
- I start Apache (*httpd.exe*), see no errors (neither inside the *error.log* file)

Now, when I open the file that outputs `phpinfo()` I don't see the extension anywhere. The `sqlsrv_connect()` is undefined.

I don't see where the PHP related errors are saved (maybe is not configured yet) and I am just stuck after trying thousands of solutions. Can't believe how hard is this in our century. PHP is really old but I really need to have this working.

Answer (score 2):

print phpinfo() and and find sqlsrv. if you'r not able to find in phpinfo()
then, go to wamp and enable the extension my be you have not enable the extension , same issue happens with me so.. pls check

Comment: also you can use odbc_connect() instead of sqlsrv_connect() odbc supports inbuild in wamp. so it's easy way to connect then sqlsrv_connect().

Comment: Thanks. Very important! Make sure you use the correct php.ini file. PHP was looking for php.ini in C:\Windows and my file was not there.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using wamp with 64bit than you need to use unofficial Microsoft SQL Server Driver for PHP (sqlsrv)

Comment: i downloaded it from http://robsphp.blogspot.com/2012/06/unofficial-microsoft-sql-server-driver.html